# Which airline offer flying for unaccompanied children (below 12 years)?

Tags: legal, airlines, children, solo-travel, minors

If you search for cheap flights with some flights search engines the problem is that you cannot send children alone.

Is there a list of airlines accepting [unaccompanied minors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unaccompanied_minor) younger than 12 years?

Comment: Generally must full-service airlines will offer it, but often only on point-to-point flights. It's a much smaller number that'll accept unaccompanied minors on a flight with a connection

Comment: From where are you trying to fly and to where are you trying to go?

Comment: @Calchas: Travel between Germany and Spain.

Comment: @Gagravarr Is your information based your experience or is there any law or something that would substantiate your claim?

Comment: I have heard of parents flying one of the cheap airlines out with their child and return alone, and a few weeks later out alone and back home with their child as that was cheaper than the unaccompanied minor travel (just the child) for the same trip.

Comment: @erik Based on what I've read on Flyertalk. If you look through [this thread](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1239006-iad-gate-agent-unacceptably-rude-unaccompanied-minors.html) you'll see lots of UM info in amongst other stuff, look for posts like [this one](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/16765195-post34.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most major airlines offer what is known as "Unaccompanied Minor" service.  You will not see it as a booking option online, as normally you, the parent or guardian, need to call the airline to arrange this. It is an extra fee on top of the airfare.

With the service, an airline or airport staff member will accompany the minor from check in to the gate and then hand them over to the gate staff / cabin crew.  At each subsequent airport, a ground staff will accompany the minor through to their next flight or to baggage claim where parents / relatives / legal guardians are waiting. Some airports allow the parents to accompany the child until the first gate.

Luftansa does offer this for 50 Euros per leg and I imagine if you google a bit you will find many other European carriers offering something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Frontier Airlines
http://www.frontierairlines.com/fron...nied-minors.do
We're sorry but we won't accept unaccompanied minors who are under five years of age.

### Children under the age of five must be accompanied by an individual 15 years or older.

We consider children from ages five to 14 to be unaccompanied minors when traveling without a companion of at least 15 years of age.

### Unaccompanied minors ages five to 14 are accepted only when non-stop service is available.

Children who are age 15 to 17 may also receive the benefits of an unaccompanied minor if the parent or guardian requests special supervision.

### Although they can't vote or drive, passengers who are 15 years of age are defined as adults.

Children traveling unaccompanied pay a full adult fare. We charge a service fee of $40 per segment per child to cover extra handling and free DIRECTV® service.

United Airlines
http://www.united.com/page/article/0,6722,1052,00.html
United offers unaccompanied minor service for children from 5-17 years of age.

The service is mandatory for unaccompanied minors 5 to 11 years old and optional for 12- to 17-year-olds. If the child is traveling as an unaccompanied minor, he or she may not travel on the last direct or connecting flight of the day. The fee is $99 USD each way (except to/from Japan).

5-7 years
Children ages 5-7 may travel on United flights that are nonstop or do not require a change of airplane. They may not travel on connecting flights. They may also travel on the last non-stop flight of the day.

8-11 years
Children ages 8-11 may travel on United non-stop, direct and connecting flights. (A direct flight makes a stop but there is no plane change.) They may also travel unaccompanied on connecting flights to other airlines. Children ages 8-11 are restricted from connecting to the last flight of the day which includes the last direct flight of the day. An exception can be made for children connecting to and from international flights.

12-17 years (Optional)
Unaccompanied minor service is available, but not required, for this age group. We strongly recommend that teenagers who are not using our unaccompanied minor service be confirmed on flights early in the day. Unanticipated delays or cancellations and unexpected weather such as fog, snow, thunderstorms or air traffic congestion may disrupt flight schedules and result in misconnections. If delays result in travel the following day, United may not be able to offer overnight accommodations since many hotels will not accept minors aged 17 or younger. If unaccompanied minor service is requested, standard fees will apply.

If a child aged 12-17 years is traveling as an unaccompanied minor, he or she will be accepted under the conditions specified for unaccompanied minors aged 8-11 years.

When two or more unaccompanied minors are traveling together, the most restrictive age requirement will apply. For example, an 11-year-old traveling with a 6-year-old may only travel on nonstop flights or flights that do not require a change of airplane.

Fees
There is a $99.00 fee for unaccompanied minors traveling on United flights worldwide. The fee applies in each direction of travel. Two or more children who are immediate family members traveling together will be assessed one fee each direction.

US Airways
Children under 5 may not travel without parent or legal guardian.
Children 5-14 may travel unaccompanied on non-stop flights for an additional $50 fee each way. US Airways assistance is required.
Children 15-17 may travel unaccompanied on non-stop and connecting flights without US Airways assistance.
Children 15-17 who require US Airways assistance may travel unaccompanied on non-stop flights only. There is an additional $50 fee each way. Uniformed employees provide assistance for children traveling alone from the point of departure to their final destination. Personnel are not qualified to provide certain types of medical assistance, and are not permitted to administer or dispense medication. Please take these points into consideration if the child requires specialized care.
If an unaccompanied minor is traveling on a flight operated by one of our Star Alliance or codeshare partners, you must contact the carrier directly for their policies on unaccompanied minors.